# silex do i need composer to autoload?

Tags: composer-php, silex

I install my web site on ovh server but i think composer it not install on it.
So i have a fatal error 
 Class 'App\Models\Product\ProductModel' not found in /home/xxxxx/App/Controller/Home/HomeController.php on line 26

in my ftp i have

```
composer.json
App
  bootstrap.php
  Model
    Product
      ProductModel.php
  Controller
    indexController.php
    Home
      HomeController.php
www
  index.php
```

I auto load App as App

Do you know if the problem is composer?
Do you know if i can use with out composer?
How?

thank you

Comment: How did you installed the project? By uploading all files by ftp?

Comment: It's ok i resolve the problem by register the namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Composer before you upload your code. Composer need not be executed on the server - in fact this is regarded more of a problem than a solution because it requires all package hosting servers to be up, and the command line tools for accessing version control systems be installed (at least as a fallback).

The recommended way to use Composer is to run it locally (or on a deployment machine that is local enough), let it fetch all files, create the autoloader, and then copy all the collected files to the target server.

This approach also resolves the problem with Composer requiring about 1GB of memory (or more, depending on how many packages have to be considered) when being run - if your web server has less memory installed, you won't be able to use Composer.